# Run a background service in android (API Level >=25) by disabling battery optimisation

Tags: android, android-studio, service, background

I have seen many apps running in background without putting a notification in front of user, like some call record apps etc, I am developing an app which runs in background with getting killed by android system, In those apps i have seen in settings that one option called "App can run in the background when not in use" is checked. So now how can i implement this programmatically without showing annoying notification to the end user ?

Note: In android Oreo the background service runs flawlessly when the battery optimization is turned off for that app manually in the settings.
 You can see the settings menu image in the link.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3pbl.png)

Thank you for in Advance :)

Comment: What kind of work do you want to run?

Comment: I'm building a call recording app, implemented a service for it to run in background.

Comment: Okay, so may be you dont need to make extra long live service. Just `BrodcastReceiver` and `IntentService`?

Comment: The service detects incoming and outgoing calls real time and records it, as

Comment: `Serevice` is NOT for detection something, `BrodcastReciever` suite's for this

Comment: I'm new to android programming, with much difficult i could complete writing this Android Service.  The problem is that, as soon the service starts in background when the boot completes, the android system kills the process, and the recording stops, the service calls onDestroy() method and kills the process.

Comment: Same happens when the app is removed from recents.

Comment: I write what you should do in my second comment

Comment: I could use a foreground service to let the app run in background by putting the notification in front of the user, i think it's just annoying, so thinking of getting a workaround for this.

Comment: Are you even listen to me?

Comment: Yes but the recording stuff should happen in a service right ?, sorry cannot comment some more, stack overflow is forbidding me.

Comment: `IntentService` not same as `Service`. Read about it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go through it :)